# I need the button to always be down

Tags: html, css, sass, css-transitions

Currently the button is always below the last element that exists in the view.
Then I add bottom: 2px and position: absolute to the button and it goes to the bottom, but when I open the drop-down the screen is enlarged and the button is not at the bottom.

It currently works like this. I want it to continue working like this, but with the button at the bottom
[image]
[image]

**Placing bottom: 2px and position: absolute the button goes to the bottom but when the drop-down is opened it overlaps.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would use flexbox

Comment: instead of `absolute` use `fixed`

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
   .card-one{display:flex;}
   .card-section{display:flex;margin:5px;text-align:center; min-height:300px;background:#000; flex-direction: column;  width:33%;color:#fff;}
   .card-section h2{color:#fff;}
   .card-section .book-btn{margin-top:auto;}
</style>

  <div class="card-one">
    <div class="card-section">
      <h2>Hello One</h2>
       <button class="btn book-btn">Book Now</button> 
     </div>
     <div class="card-section">
       <h2>Hello One</h2>
        <button class="btn book-btn">Book Now</button> 
    </div>
  
 </div>
```